# Spring MVC -- Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm working on a Spring 3.1 MVC application, and my JSP won't come up.  I am getting the following in my browser screen.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /GuestBook.jsp at line 31

28:     <form:form method="post" action="GuestBook.jsp">
29:         <table>
30:             <tr>
31:                 <td><form:label path="comment.name">Name</form:label></td>
32:                 <td><form:input path="comment.name" /></td>
33:             </tr>
34:             <tr>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:524)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:429)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)


root cause 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.GuestBook_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(GuestBook_jsp.java:269)
    org.apache.jsp.GuestBook_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(GuestBook_jsp.java:214)
    org.apache.jsp.GuestBook_jsp._jspService(GuestBook_jsp.java:127)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Here is the full form.

```
<form:form method="post" action="GuestBook.jsp">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="comment.name">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="comment.name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="comment.message">Message</form:label></td>
            <td><form:textarea path="comment.message" rows="10" cols="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit comment" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

This is what I have in my controller class.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("GuestBook")
public class CommentController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/GuestBook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addComment(@ModelAttribute("comment") Comment comment, BindingResult result) {
        CommentDAO commentDAO = new CommentDAO();
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
        comment.setDate(date);

        if (commentDAO.writeComment(comment) == true) {
            return "redirect:GuestBook.jsp";
        }

        return "redirect:Oops.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/GuestBook")
    public ModelAndView showComments() {
        return new ModelAndView("comments", "command", new Comment());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) As Biju said add modelAttribute="comment"

2) Change comment.name, comment.message to name, message

3) Rework your GET handler:

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addCommentForm(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("comment", new Comment());
        return "comments";
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to bind your `form:form` to a model or command object, if you don't explicitly specify, the taglib assumes that there is a model attribute called `command`.You can do this:

```
<form:form method="post" action="GuestBook.jsp" modelAttribute="comment">
 <table>
    <tr>
        ...
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
       ...
```

Comment: I made your suggested changes, but it's giving me the same error with one slight difference.  It's now saying comment isn't available as a request attribute.

Comment: Oops, i am sorry, I did not see your /GuestBook path, you are indeed binding with "command" as the model name, you just have to remove "comment.name", you have put it just as "name".

Comment: I've changed it to just name, and I'm getting the same error message, except instead of command, it's saying there's no bean named comment available as a request attribute.

Comment: So you have your original form WITHOUT modelAttribute and you are still getting this error right.

Comment: That is correct.  When I leave it out, the error references command, and when I put it in, it references the model object.

Comment: What is your url like when you are accessing the page? Also your mapping in web.xml is not recommended one - `*.*`, instead it would be better to put it as `/*`

Comment: I tried changing my mapping to /*.*, but it told me it was an invalid <url-pattern>.  I got the same message when I tried changing it to /*.html.

Comment: I changed my <url-pattern> to /*, but now I am getting a different error.  I will post a new thread, since that is a separate question.