# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute in spring mvc

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat, jsp-tags

Please someone help I've been searching for this error for the whole day, But I cannot find a precise answer.I want my controller to take me to the **LoginModel.jsp.**

This is my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/LoginModel",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String requestLogin(){
    return "LoginModel";
}
```

This is My JSP **LoginModel.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"></head>
<body>
<form:form method = "POST" action = "/HelpDesk/login">
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td><form:label path = "username">username</form:label></td>
           <td><form:input path = "username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><form:label path = "password">password</form:label></td>
           <td><form:input path = "password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><form:label path = "role">role</form:label></td>
           <td><form:input path = "role" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan = "2">
              <input type = "submit" value = "submit"/>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>  
  </form:form>
```

This is the error I am getting

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/LoginModel.jsp at line 12

9:  <form:form method = "POST" action = "/HelpDesk/login">
10:         <table>
11:             <tr>
12:                <td><form:label path = "username">username</form:label></td>
13:                <td><form:input path = "username" /></td>
14:             </tr>
15:             <tr>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:465)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.LoginModel_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(LoginModel_jsp.java:193)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.LoginModel_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(LoginModel_jsp.java:127)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.LoginModel_jsp._jspService(LoginModel_jsp.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC -- Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479727/spring-mvc-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-comma)

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA I've tried using the ModelAttribute and working around the GET method, still it does not work.

Comment: Did you add `modelAttribute` attribute to <form:form> tag?